# Use of compile time derivable types in F# templates

Tags: class, templates, generics, f#

In the following code, I would like to instantiate a templated class using a variable's type, ultimately as a generic variable passed into a function, but even this simpler form doesn't work:

```
type saveXY<'a when 'a:comparison> (x:'a,y:'a) =
    member this.X = x
    member this.Y = y
    member this.lessThan () = this.X < this.Y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let x1 = 3
    let y1 = 7
    let saver1 = new saveXY<int>(x1,y1)            // Good
    printfn "%A" (saver1.lessThan())

    let x2 = 3.0
    let y2 = 7.0
    let saver2 = new saveXY<float>(x2,y2)          // Good
    printfn "%A" (saver2.lessThan())

    let saver3 = new saveXY<x2.GetType()> (x2,y2)  // No Good, see errors

    0
```

However, for `saver3` below I get (and I cant find info on FS1241):

```
...\Program.fs(23,39): error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '(' in type arguments. Expected ',' or other token.
...\CompareProblem\Program.fs(23,39): error FS1241: Expected type argument or static argument
```

If you remove the templating on `saveXY`, then `saver2` is in error as `saver1` causes the `saveXY` class arguments to be constrained to ints.

I also experimented with declaring x and y as simply `obj`, but that doesn't work. I suspect that the problem is that this simply that this is not possible,
that is if the class argument types are generic they are derived once (from first use). On the other hand, maybe I am missing something.

Is there a way to use variable-based types, which would be determinable at compile time, as type template arguments in F#? Is there another way to create a type that is capable of handling/storing generic values?

**UPDATE**: From Lee's suggestion, this works, if you template the class and then just use `<_>` to instantiate it will work:

```
type saveXY<'a when 'a:comparison> (x:'a, y:'a) =
    member this.X = x
    member this.Y = y
    member this.lessThan () = this.X < this.Y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let x1 = 3
    let y1 = 7
    let saver3 = new saveXY<_> (x1,y1)  // works, 'a is int
    printfn "%A" (saver3.lessThan())

    let x2 = 3.0
    let y2 = 7.0
    let saver3 = new saveXY<_> (x2,y2)  // works, 'a is float
    printfn "%A" (saver3.lessThan())

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore  // wait for a key
    0
```

But why do I need to template the class type, as I suggested above? It would seem that the compiler is deducing the types anyway when I use `<_>` so why can't I simply use (as I would for a function):

```
type saveXY(x, y) =  // x and y are generic, no? They only require comparison, yes?
    member this.X = x
    member this.Y = y
    member this.lessThan () = this.X < this.Y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let x1 = 3
    let y1 = 7
    let saver3 = new saveXY (x1,y1)  // works
    printfn "%A" (saver3.lessThan())

    let x2 = 3.0
    let y2 = 7.0
    let saver3 = new saveXY (x2,y2)  // But this FAILS with error FS0001
    printfn "%A" (saver3.lessThan())

    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore  // wait for a key
    0
```

Comment: No you can't specify type parameters like this although you already know the type of `x2` and `y2` statically, so your use case isn't clear.

Comment: Not very clear what exactly you're trying to do: are you trying to build code that will instantiate you class with generic argument that _is not known at compile time_, or do you simply want to say "_whatever type `x2` is, please use that_", and have compiler figure it out?

Comment: Its the: _simply want to say "whatever type x2 is, please use that", and have compiler figure it out?_ case - in the example above, I would like `saver3` to be instantiated with a float template type, since `x2` is a float. In the real code, x2 will be a function argument of generic type, but where the function is instantiated with different compile time types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the compiler to infer the type of the generic parameter you can use:

```
let saver3 = new saveXY<_>(x2, y2)
```

or

```
let saver3 = saveXY(x2, y2)
```

Comment: The second form does not work, but the first does - see UPDATE

Comment: @user1857742 - Which version of F# are you using? The second form might require F# 4

Comment: I think its 3.1 - in Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 2):

F# does not have any built-in method for instantiating generic code with a type known at runtime. You can always do that via reflection, but it is not useful very often - you won't be actually able to do much with the value if you create it using reflection.

For the sake of the example, you could move `LessThan` into a separate interface:

```
type ILessThan = 
  abstract LessThan : unit -> bool

type SaveXY<'T when 'T:comparison> (x:'T,y:'T) =
  member this.X = x
  member this.Y = y
  interface ILessThan with 
    member this.LessThan () = 
      printfn "Comparing values of type: %s" (typeof<'T>.Name)
      this.X < this.Y
```

Given a `System.Type` and two `obj` values representing the arguments, you can create an instance of `SaveXY<T>` at runtime using reflection with `typeof<T>` being the given `System.Type`:

```
let createSaveXY typ x y = 
  let typ = typedefof<SaveXY<_>>.MakeGenericType [| typ |]
  typ.GetConstructors().[0].Invoke([| x; y |]) :?> ILessThan
```

Here is an example of how this works:

```
let lt = createSaveXY (typeof<float>) (box 3.0) (box 7.0)
lt.LessThan()
```

But as I said earlier, this is rarely useful and it is not super efficient - so rather than copying this, try to describe the problem that you're trying to solve - there is probably a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - I don't want to instantiate the class with a type known only at runtime, but a generic one that is an argument of a function.